# JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, powershell, firefox

I have create one JSON file through PowerShell and place it on serve.

When i access that JOSN file through **$.getJSON** it works fine in crome and IE browser but when i access that JSON file in Firefox i got error of

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

**Header:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

What should be issue and how to fix it in firefox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743994/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-json-dat

Comment: It's clearly a character set identification issue, the server appears to be replying with UTF-16. What is the `Content-Type` header in the response?

Comment: @Rino in that question the issues was relative to PHP. And i have tried that all solution but no luck.

Comment: @T.J. I am requesting through $.getJSON(Url) in which no need to pass Content-Type

Comment: @DOM: There's always a need for the server to correctly identify the character set of a resource when it supplies it. More: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) Again: What is the `Content-Type` header **in the response**. You can find it in the Network tab.

Comment: I have checked in header in which i have found that Content-Type is "text/plain"

Answer (score 1):

You've said that the server sends that JSON back with `Content-Type: text/plain`. The data appears to be in UTF-16 (probably, that's based on the screenshot), but the default charset for `text/plain` is `us-ascii` (see §4.1.2 of [RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1.2)):

> 4.1.2.  Charset Parameter
>
> A critical parameter that may be specified in the Content-Type field
> for "text/plain" data is the character set.  This is specified with a
> "charset" parameter, as in:
>
> ```
> Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
> ```
>
> Unlike some other parameter values, the values of the charset
> parameter are NOT case sensitive.  The default character set, which
> must be assumed in the absence of a charset parameter, is US-ASCII.

So, you need to change the response from the server such that it correctly identifies the character set being used, e.g. `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-16` (obviously ensuring first that that is, in fact, the charset of the resource).

---

I'll just note that, from what I can make out of the JSON, it looks like it's primarily in a western script. If so, UTF-16 is unusual and inefficient choice, you'd probably be better off with UTF-8. But I only have a small fragment of the text to work from.

Comment: Hi T.J. thanks for answer. I have update the question. Can you please look into it. i still need to change response from server? and it also works in chrome and IE. Issue only occur in Firefox.

Comment: @DOM: Yup. If the server were specifying the charset, it would be on that `Content-Type` header line. (For comparison, look at the `Content-Type` SO serves with this page.) Since it isn't, Firefox appears to be using the default according to the RFC (US-ASCII) while IE appears to see the BOM (the first two bytes of the response) and switch to treating it as UTF-16.