# convert multiple rows to json after PDO request with php and pdo method only

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I want to convert severals rows after PDO request but I can't display result on my page.

This is for use with a rubimotion app

there is my php code:

```
<?php
    //to see what return request in my php page
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    try {
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=IP;dbname=NAME','USER','PASS');

        $reponse = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1");
        $reponse->execute(); #this request return severals rows

        $nb = $reponse->rowCount();
        if($nb > 0){
            $json = json_encode( $reponse->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) );
            echo $json;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Connexion échouée : " . $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

But I have a white page and in the console the response is empty.

Whats wrong ?

I tryed many option however I have many errors like

- array to string convertion
- SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

thanks ! And sorry for the mistakes I am french

Comment: Check if you have something like single quote (') or any other character in your dataset ...

Comment: check row count by echo $nb; first for result data is available or not.Or add else part of if($nb > 0) condition

Comment: I don't have single quote juste many fields string
@BharatDangar : echo $nb -> 218 rows !

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting in PHP? Do you see any errors in your web server error log?

Comment: Did you realize you have defined `$pdo_options`, but it isn't used in your connection?

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry I use `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` is a javascript error not PHP.  How are you handling the JSON afterwards?

Comment: Check the response in your browser's network console. What is is being sent as a response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743994/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-json-dat)

Comment: @aynber the response is empty !

Comment: @Devon I don't use js

Answer (score 0):

You must removed header function & use below line. You should add below line above the json_encode function.

```
header("content-type:application/json");
```

Comment: now I have `$json = json_encode( $reponse->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) );
    var_dump($json);` in my page there is bool(false)

Comment: `header("content-type:application/json");

$reponse = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM manager_vtours WHERE user_id = 1");

echo json_encode($reponse->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`

result = []

Comment: I don't have error... juste an empty response in my console and a white page